# What values can $2^j-3^k$ have?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

What values can $2^j-3^k$ have?

E.g., 
$$
2^2-3^1=1\\
2^2-3^0=3\\ 
2^3-3^1=5\\ 
2^4-3^2=7
$$

Can every number not divisible by $2$ or $3$ be written as $2^j-3^k$? If not, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we try to find an $n$  coprime to $6$ such that $2^j-3^k$ doesn't cover all options $\bmod n$.

Since we want $2^j$ to cover a small number of cases we are going to try with $n=2^m-1$.

We find that the order of $3\bmod 511$ is $12$ and the order of $2\bmod 511$ is clearly $9$.

Thus only a small fraction of residues $\bmod 511$ are covered by $2^j-3^k$.

Comment: ... namely, at most $9\cdot12$. +1

Comment: Using $m=2^{25}-1$ then $2$ has order $25$ and $3$ has order $450$ and with a small heuristic I found only $4122$ different residues of possible $11250 (=25 \cdot 450)$. Nice idea! (+1)

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure I saw you once in the Kassel science department library in the summer of 2013. I think you were reading a yellow book on the Riemann hypothesis.